# How to check if elements of a vector lies between two vectors in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say `A` and `B` are given vectors and the aim is to check which elements of `Y` lie between A and B. For example:

```
A=np.array([1,2,3,4])
B=np.array([10,20,30,40])
Y=np.array([8,15,0,50])
```

The expected output should look like:
`[1,1,0,0]` where the elements are not bool type so I can find out the number of true values, using `np.sum()`

Answer (score 3):

You can so both comparisons and take the elementwise `and`

```
(A < Y) & (Y < B)
```

A `np.sum()` will work regardless of them being boolean. When in doubt, just cast to int using

```
X.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as

```
np.logical_and(A <= Y, Y <= B).astype(int)
```

But you can also sum a logical vector, numpy will handle the conversion under the hood.

```
In [1]: np.sum(np.logical_and(A <= Y, Y <= B).astype(int)) == np.sum(np.logical_and(A <= Y, Y <= B))
Out[1]: True
```